# Protect Swagger Endpoint with Basic Auth

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui

I use Swagger in my web api project:

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>...
```

an so on. We also use SwaggerUI. Works like a charm.
For production we don't like the swagger UI to be available and we would like to protect it with basic auth. Afaik there is no such functionality available out of the box. Is there a way to do it with some kind of 'hack' in the web api? Can i register a dedicated filter only for a specific route or something like this?

Thank you for your help
regards
laurin

Answer (score 0):

The web server that you use may support enabling HTTP basic authentication for URL matching certain pattern (e.g. starting with /swagger-ui).